# Move a UIImage object across a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a UIImageView object X that is contained in an TableView object A. I want to be able to touch X and remove it from object A and move it into object B (a UIView). Both Object A & B are inside of the SplitViewController.

```
 A        B
_____    _____
|   |    |   |
| X | -> |   |
|___|    |___|
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Create a draggable UIView. Apple provides some sample code for that: [MoveMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html)
2. When dragging starts, move the `UIView` X to the first common superview (someSuperview) of viewA and viewB:

   `[someSuperview addSubview:viewX];`
3. Adjust the frame of viewX, so its absolute position will remain identical :

   `[viewA convertRect:viewX.frame toView:someSuperview];`
4. Wait for the user to perform dragging/moving.
5. After the touches end, add viewX to viewB and convert the frame again.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. In this case the superview is a SplitView Controller, I will check the documentation to see how I can adapt it. Cheers!

Comment: You can also use the SplitViewController's superview (or that view's superview...), which might be better in this case, since a `UISplitView` might do some things to its subviews, e.g. layout them in a special way.